# Сортировка родительских тегов по содержимому вложенных тегов

Tags: python, xml, сортировка

Столкнулся с проблемой при написании сортировщика XML файлов. 
Для примера есть XML вида:

```
<MAINLIST>
  <MAIN>
    <NZ>999</NZ>
    <TIP>103</TIP>
    <UNIT>
      <AA>ALPHA</AA>
      <BB>BETHA</BB>
      <CC>GAMMA</CC>
    </UNIT>
  </MAIN>
  <MAIN>
    <NZ>888</NZ>
    <TIP>100</TIP>
    <UNIT>
      <AA>ETTHA</AA>
      <BB>ZETHA</BB>
      <CC>OMEGA</CC>
    </UNIT>
  </MAIN>
</MAINLIST>
```

Таких тегов MAIN в файле может быть несколько десятков. Нужно отсортировать их внутри MAINLIST-тега по возрастанию содержимого тега TIP, то есть в приведенном случае теги MAIN должны поменяться местами. Значения в теге TIP могут повторяться у разных тегов MAIN. Сортированный файл нужно записать в тот-же файл, либо на крайний случай, в новый XML-файл.
На просторах Google есть описание подобных задач, но там во всех разобранных мною случаях сортировка происходит, если брать аналогию с моим примером, по атрибутам, либо содержимому родительского тега , либо сортируются вложенные в MAIN теги.

Может кто-то с подобным работал уже. Натолкните на верный путь, каким методом воспользоваться, ну либо подскажите как более правильно загуглить.

Заранее благодарю за любую помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Без претензий на сформированное решение но попробуйте рассмотреть такой вариант:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('test.xml') as xml:
        ws = bs(xml.read(), 'html.parser').find_all('main')

    text = '<MANIFEST>'

    for w in sorted(ws, key=lambda x: int(x.nz.text)):
        text += str(w)

    text += '</MANIFEST>'

    print(bs(text, 'html.parser').prettify(formatter=lambda x: x.title()))
# <manifest>
#  <main>
#   <nz>
#    888
#   </nz>
#   <tip>
#    100
#   </tip>
#   <unit>
#    <aa>
#     Ettha
#    </aa>
#    <bb>
#     Zetha
#    </bb>
#    <cc>
#     Omega
#    </cc>
#   </unit>
#  </main>
#  <main>
#   <nz>
#    999
#   </nz>
#   <tip>
#    103
#   </tip>
#   <unit>
#    <aa>
#     Alpha
#    </aa>
#    <bb>
#     Beta
#    </bb>
#    <cc>
#     Gamma
#    </cc>
#   </unit>
#  </main>
# </manifest>
```